# OwlCarousel-2 video plugin not displaying at all on Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

I've spent the last two hours or so trying to wrap my head around why this won't work. When I check Chrome Dev Tools, I don't get any errors stating the files can't be found etc., so I've decided to reach out to you guys. Basically, I want to know the reason why OwlCarousel won't display. There was a similar question posted that stated to use iframe tag inside div instead of anchor tag. It didn't work for me. I have jQuery, all OwlCarousel2-2.4beta files linked. Here is the relevant code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel();
});
```

```html
<head>
  <!-- OWLSLIDER STYLESHEETS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="owl.carousel.2.0.0-        beta.2.4/assets/owl.carousel.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="owl.carousel.2.0.0-beta.2.4/assets/owl.theme.default.css">

  <!-- OWLSLIDER SCRIPT -->
  <script src="owl.carousel.2.0.0-beta.2.4/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>

  <!-- JQUERY 3.1.0 -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-cCueBR6CsyA4/9szpPfrX3s49M9vUU5BgtiJj06wt/s=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <!-- 
<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.3.0/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>
  <div class="owl-carousel">
    <div class="item-video" data-merge="3">
      <iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/s8XIgR5OGJc?rel=0"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="item-video" data-merge="1">
      <iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/s8XIgR5OGJc?rel=0"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="item-video" data-merge="2">
      <iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/sbJLcWdfgq0?rel=0"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="item-video" data-merge="1">
      <a class="owl-video" href="https://youtu.be/s8XIgR5OGJc"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="item-video" data-merge="2">
      <a class="owl-video" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H3jLkJrhHKQ"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="item-video" data-merge="3">
      <a class="owl-video" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g3J4VxWIM6s"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="item-video" data-merge="1">
      <a class="owl-video" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0fhoIate4qI"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="item-video" data-merge="2">
      <a class="owl-video" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EF_kj2ojZaE"></a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Scripts -->
  <script src="js/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="owl.carousel.2.0.0-beta.2.4/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-cCueBR6CsyA4/9szpPfrX3s49M9vUU5BgtiJj06wt/s=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="js/html5shiv.js" type="text/js"></script>
  <script src="js/html5shiv-printshiv.js" type="text/js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

I have both anchors and iframes in now, just to show. I have tried both and neither have worked. Does anyone know how to fix this?